# script to search several websites at once

Tags: javascript

I’d like to use javascript to search the same keyword on several websites.

for example, on this website, when I type "XXXX" in the search bar I get [this result](http://www.semencesdupuy.com/fr/catalogsearch/result/?q=%D0%A5%D0%A5%D0%A5%D0%A5&x=0&y=0). In this case, it’s very easy to use the url to look for another keyword.

But [this other website](http://www.biaugerme.com/) is using a javascript based search engine, and when I search a keyword, the url doesn’t change. 
The code this search bar uses looks like this :

```
    <li class="lirecherche">
        <input name="rechercher" value="rechercher" onclick="this.value=''" />
    <a href="javascript:document.formchercher.submit();" style=" text-decoration: none;">OK</a></li>

Is there a way to send a search request to this website from a script or an url ? (not a script that automatically type the keyword and press enter for me, but which is actually doing the research)
```

EDIT :

It is refering to this form. There is this `method="post"` but it doesn’t seem to appear anywhere else in the code. how can I find where it’s going ?

```
            <form name="formchercher" id="formchercher" method="post" action="">
    <table height="94" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="menuH">
        <tr>
        <td width="37" valign="bottom" id="acc"><a href="index.php" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('bnav0','','images/env/nav/b_acc_ov.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/env/nav/b_acc_on.jpg" name="bnav0" alt="retour accueil" width="51" height="85" border="0" /></a></td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="b2"><a href="potageres_2.php" onclick="ouvre_menu(2,'rub')" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('bnav2','','images/env/nav/b2_ov.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/env/nav/b2_off.jpg" name="bnav2" border="0" id="bnav2"  /><br />
          Potagères</a></td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="b3"><a href="fleurs_3.php" onclick="ouvre_menu(3,'rub')" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('bnav3','','images/env/nav/b3_ov.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/env/nav/b3_off.jpg" name="bnav3" border="0" id="bnav3"  /><br />
          Fleurs</a></td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="b4"><a href="aromatiques_4.php" onclick="ouvre_menu(4,'rub')" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('bnav4','','images/env/nav/b4_ov.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/env/nav/b4_off.jpg" name="bnav4" border="0" id="bnav4"  /><br />
          Aromatiques</a></td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="b5"><a href="cadeau_5.php" onclick="ouvre_menu(5,'rub')" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('bnav5','','images/env/nav/b5_ov.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/env/nav/b5_off.jpg" name="bnav5" border="0" id="bnav5"  /><br />
          Cadeau</a></td>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="b6"><a href="engrais-verts_6.php" onclick="ouvre_menu(6,'rub')" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('bnav6','','images/env/nav/b6_ov.jpg',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/env/nav/b6_off.jpg" name="bnav6" border="0" id="bnav6"  /><br />
          Engrais&nbsp;verts</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the form stored in "document.formchercher" it will almost certainly be a parent of the input field. It should have its action and method in its opening tag.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a bit more research I figured out what to do :

```
<form name="formchercher" id="formchercher" method="post" action="">
```

This form has no action. it means will submit to the index.php page whose this form is.

I just had to fill the action with the complete URL as such :

```
<form name="formchercher" id="formchercher" method="post" action="http://www.biaugerme.com/index.php">
```

This way I can do the research from my own html page, and it opens the result on their website.